# c++ getline doesn't get the input

Tags: c++, codeblocks, cin, getline

i am trying to input a line and then an integer then a line again however when it the last cin gets the line it and i press enter it crashes or outputs randomly to the infinity. whats wrong?

```
int main(){
    string a= "", b = "";
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;

    getline(cin, a);
    cin >> n1;

    //when i input the next like it outputs randomly without continuing with the next like why?
    getline(cin, b);

    //it doesn't let me to input here coz it's outputting some random strings.
    cin >> n2;
    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate for your help, thanks.

Comment: `it crashes or outputs randomly` I have a feeling you aren't showing the code you are using because there's no way the code above should crash or even output. In any case `getline(cin, b);` doesn't do what you think it does, you probably have a newline in your buffer left over from  `cin >> n1;`, so `getline(cin, b);` reads that newline, and then `cin >> n2;` tries to read whatever you expected to be read into `b` and presumably fails.

Comment: Don't mix `getline` with `cin >>` type input. It never works as you expect.

Comment: its not actually crashing but outputting random text.

Comment: For these kinds of questions, you should have copy-and-pasted your exact input, as your code will "work" for some inputs and not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consume the newline character.

```
int main(){
    string a, b;
    int n1, n2;

    getline(cin, a);

    cin >> n1;
    cin.get(); // this will consume the newline
    getline(cin, b);

    cin >> n2;
    cin.get(); // this will consume the newline
}
```

`std::getline` will consume the newline for you.

Here's example usage:

```
21:42 $ cat test.cc 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string a, b;
    int n1, n2;

    getline(cin, a);

    cin >> n1;
    cin.get(); // this will consume the newline
    getline(cin, b);

    cin >> n2;
    cin.get(); // this will consume the newline

    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << n1 << n2 << std::endl;
}
✔ ~ 
21:42 $ g++ test.cc
✔ ~ 
21:42 $ ./a.out 
hello
4
world
2
hello world 42
```

Comment: thanks, while ago i dont use c++ and i forgot cin.get(). Thanks you bro.

Comment: `get` can be problematic... it reads exactly one character, so if there's any trailing whitespace after the number then you won't have consumed the "newline" as intended.  Walt's suggestion to use `ignore` is more robust, though ignoring input's dangerous too: using `skipws` then checking the next character is a newline is more robust.  The OP's code doesn't do any error checking though, so the benchmark's low.

Comment: I would tend to use getline exclusively, but he wanted the reason it wasn't working.

Comment: i didn't know i could input numbers without treating them as string. however when i used ignore it ignored the next cin. why does it happens @TonyD?

Comment: @kobbycoder: without seeing your actual input and attempt to use ignore, it's hard to say.  A working version's available [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96602c91d25ad266) for reference/comparison.

Comment: @TonyD This is a bit out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

For your case after your `cin` you should use `cin.ignore()` rather than `cin.get()` like this:

`cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: i used ignore before however it skipped the 3rd cin