# std::getline not re-requesting user input in while loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program where a user is asked for input and then I check if the 2 sub strings (splitting in half) is the mirror image. I want to loop continually until a user stops entering in input but my code is not looping correctly. The code works fine on the first iteration of the `while` loop, but then during the second iteration of the `while` loop, `getline()` does not re-request user input, it just sets `std::string input` to "".

I'm sure I am missing something obvious.

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool compareMirrorString(const std::string&, const std::string&);

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    string first_string;
    string second_string;
    bool result;
    int input_length;
    int first_string_length;
    std::string quit;

    cout << "Enter 2 strings to compare, seperated by a # e.g. \"abc#cba\"." << endl;

    while ( true )
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        //split string into its two component parts
        input_length = input.length();
        first_string_length = input_length / 2;
        first_string.assign(input, 0, first_string_length);
        second_string.assign(input, first_string_length + 1);

        //test if two strings are mirror images of each other

        result = compareMirrorString(first_string, second_string);

        if (result) {
            cout << "Yes they match.";
        }
        else {
            cout << "No they do not match.";
        }

        cout << "\nDo you want to test another string? Y for yes, q to quit." << endl;
        cin >> quit;
        if (quit == "q" or quit == "Q" or quit == "quit" or quit == "Quit" or quit == "QUIT" 
            or quit == "no" or quit == "No") 
        {
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "Enter another 2 strings to compare, seperated by a # e.g. \"abc#cba\"." << endl;
        }

    } //end of while

    return 0;

}

//is second a mirror image of first?
bool compareMirrorString(const std::string& first, const std::string& second) 
{

    if (first.length() != second.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    //put first_string on stack    
    std::stack<char> stackChar;

    for (auto elem : first){
        stackChar.push(elem);
    }

    int size = stackChar.size();

    //compare first and second strings
    bool compare_equal = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (stackChar.top() == second[i])
        {
            stackChar.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            compare_equal = false;
            break;
        }  
    }

    return compare_equal;

}
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990640/c-getline-doesnt-get-the-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first iteration of the loop:

```
cin >> quit;
```

will read up to, but not including the newline character.

In the second iteration of the loop:

```
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

will read that newline character, and hence read an empty string into `input`.

There are several ways to fix this

1. You could use `getline` to read the string `quit`
2. You could read `input` again, if it happens to be an empty string.
3. You could call `cin.get();` after the `cin >> quit` to clear the newline.